# ACTION_FOUND Broadcast inside bound service

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-broadcastreceiver

Мне необходимо выполнить поиск bluetooth устройств внутри привязанной службы (bounded service) с помощью функции startdiscovery. Для этого надо установить broadcast receiver внутри службы. Но это требует получение контекста, а его у привязанной службы нет. Статическое создание ресивера через манифест тоже требует в конечном счете наличие контекста в ресивере.

```
    <receiver android:name=".SingBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action,ACTION_FOUND"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Есть ли способ это сделать в привязанной службе?

Comment: Мне необходимо выполнить поиск bluetooth устройств внутри привязанной службы (bounded service) с помощью функции startdiscovery. Для этого надо установить broadcast receiver внутри службы. Но это требует получение контекста, а его у привязанной службы нет. Статическое создание ресивера через манифест тоже требует в конечном счете наличие контекста  в ресивере. Есть ли способ  это сделать в привязанной службе?

Comment: А что не так с контекстом в службе и ресивере? Служба сама является потомком контекста, а в ресивер он приходит параметром во время получения события

Comment: Чтобы зарегистрировать broadcast receiver уже нужен контекст. И речь идет о привязанной удаленной службе (построенной на AIDL) переслать в нее контекст нельзя - я так понимаю, это не parcelable.тип.

Comment: Контекст службе отдаёт система, точно так же, как и активности. Передавать его туда не нужно - сама служба и есть контекст.

Comment: Привязанный сервис имеет свой собственный APK. Мне надо зарегистрировать ресивер, статически через манифест это не получается (см. выше). Динамически - я должен получить ссылку на контекст так как для регистрации ресивера нужен метод контекста. Тогда вопрос к вам, как получить контекст для регистрации ресивера в привязанном сервисе. Так что ли - ((Context)this).registerReceiver(.....)?

Comment: В манифесте на новых API не все ресиверы можно регистрировать. А внутри службы - можно и как у Вас и `this.registerReceiver(.....)` и можно `this` опустить , хотя мне ещё не приходилось это делать именно в службе, возможно есть ещё нюансы... В общем пробуйте.